# Alternative of Iframe

Tags: html, iframe, frames, x-frame-options

one of our client was loading our web application in there website by an iframe. Few days back we applied X-Frame-Options Deny to our Application which somehow stopped loading our application in there website. Due to some reasons we can't change X-Frame-Options Deny, so is there any alternative , client can load our web application. Tried with Html Object but didn't worked for me.

Thanks,
Abhinav

Comment: you could allow from their domain only: `X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM=http://www.example.com` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: I can't change X-Frame-Options Deny, m bound not to change it

Comment: well then you'll have to either write an api for them to consume or enter a world of pain with cors and ajax - but that would be even less secure than the iframe allowed by one domain

Comment: Can you help me out where i can get info that using it with with cors and ajax is Less secure

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236746/which-is-more-secure-iframe-or-cors-for-creating-a-widget-intended-for-embed